# Manjaro not booting after kernel and graphic's card drivers update

Tags: boot, grub, nvidia, manjaro

I had a problem with the nvidia-utils package and the proprietary drivers for my graphics card (gtx 1660 super), I posted a question here while I was researching by myself, when I got the solution it looked like it worked, but when I was restarting to use the new kernel (I just deleted the nvidia package and ran `sudo pacman -Syyu` to update everything) it didn't give me any video, it was stuck in my bios loading screen or something like that.

I don't know what happened, maybe some weird package conflict broke everything, I already have all my important files recovered from windows but I don't want to reinstall a configure all my system again.

Comment: Please elaborate: do you get to the `grub` menu? Also, after removing the old drivers and installing the new ones, did everything work when you rebooted?

Comment: I get to the grub menu, I can choose windows or manjaro and I can work perfectly fine from windows, the problem is when I try to boot manjaro, I don't receive any video signal, just the asus motherboard logo like if it was loading or something, I don't know what happened but when I updated it pacman said the usual "the new kernel will be applied at restart" or something like that

Comment: This is exactly the problem I just encountered. There were dependency warnings just before I updated everything (I think the warnings referenced nvidia-utils). Now the system just hangs on the mainboard splash screen. I tried a bunch of things from an alternate TTY, including downgrading nvidia-utils and lib32-nvidia-blah... but this did nothing. Looking at the x server log, i see "failed to initialize the NVIDIA kernel module." So, I brought everything back up to the current versions and am researching the x server errors...

Comment: I've posted three questions related to this with several different things that could be happening, today it gave me an error, it passed the motherboard logo and said something about error with "ligth display manager", it says display so I will reinstall manjaro but with open source drivers to see what happens.